# How to parse json response using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova

I am new to phone gap application development and 
I am trying to call a web service from my app for getting data from the server. **I am succeeded to call a REST web service but getting problem with the parsing of JSON response using JavaScript**.

My code for calling the service is as follow:

```
     $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://www.url.php",
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert("success!");

                    },
                    error: function(request, status, error) {
                    console.log("Error status " + status);
                    console.log("Error request status text: " + request.statusText);
                    console.log("Error request status: " + request.status);
                    console.log("Error request response text: " + request.responseText);
                    console.log("Error response header: " + request.getAllResponseHeaders());
                    }
            });
```

I am able to get in to the success block of the code but the problem is i am not able to parse the response using JavaScript.
Please guide or help me to acheive the task.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to use `JSON.parse` for parsing resonse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it done as follow:

```
     $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://www.url.php",
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(response) {

                    //entered in the success block means our service call is succeeded properly

                        var resp = JSON.stringify(response.text); // we are accessing the text from the json object(response) and then converting it in to the string format 
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(response)); // print the response in console
                        alert(resp); // alert the response

                    },
                    error: function(request, status, error) {
                    console.log("Error status " + status);
                    console.log("Error request status text: " + request.statusText);
                    console.log("Error request status: " + request.status);
                    console.log("Error request response text: " + request.responseText);
                    console.log("Error response header: " + request.getAllResponseHeaders());
                    }
            });
```

and you can refer the json object : **{"text":"Login success","status":1,"school_detail_id":"72","data":[{"section_id":"541","class_name":"1-A"},{"section_id":"542","class_name":"2-A"}]}**

so the alert will be showing Login success/fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(response) {
   var resp = JSON.parse(response);
   alert(resp.text); // Login success or Fail
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.